# Symbol for Bring radical/ultraradical?

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to find the symbol, such as is given on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ultraradical.html which represents the solution to `$x^5+x-a=0$`, and which is sometimes called a "Bring radical" or an "ultraradical".  Is there such a thing somewhere in any LaTeX package?

Comment: Please post a picture rather than an external link. Thanks. Do you have any other references on this symbol? It is not in unicode as far as I know. You should just use symbols, which others will understand... just a recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `tikz` answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\ultrarad}[1]{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[inner ysep=0pt] (a) {\strut$#1$};
   \draw[rounded corners=0.5ex] ([shift={(-0.5ex,0.7ex)}]a.south west) --
             ([shift={(-0.5ex,0ex)}]a.south west)--
             ([shift={(0.5ex,0ex)}]a.south west) --
             ([shift={(0.5ex,1.3ex)}]a.south west) --
             (a.north west) ;
   \draw[shorten <= -0.04ex] (a.north west) -- (a.north east);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 }
\begin{document}
  \ultrarad{a} \ultrarad{abcdg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks - this is a perfect solution for me!